# Filter servlet causing image, css and JS not displaying on client while URL Pattern of Filter Servelet is /* and Servlet URL Pattern is /

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I newbie is Java, I have implement Authentication mechanism, for this i have developed a filter class and a servlet for the same.

My all authentication is working fine instead image, css and JS file loading.

My Servlet mappring in web.xml is:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FederationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.auth10.federation.WSFederationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>login-page-url</param-name>
      <param-value>login.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>exclude-urls-regex</param-name>
      <param-value>/image/</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FederationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ClaimServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.pspl.adfs.sso.ClaimServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ClaimServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

My Filter servlet is:

```
package com.auth10.federation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class WSFederationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String PRINCIPAL_SESSION_VARIABLE = "FederatedPrincipal";

    private String loginPage;
    private String excludedUrlsRegex;

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WSFederationFilter.class);

    public WSFederationFilter() {
        logger.debug("constructing");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        logger.debug("initializing");
        this.loginPage = config.getInitParameter("login-page-url");
        this.excludedUrlsRegex = config.getInitParameter("exclude-urls-regex");
        System.out.println("excludedUrlsRegex <><><> " + excludedUrlsRegex);

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.debug("filtering");

        FederatedPrincipal principal = null;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        String path =  httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
            // is the request is a token?
            if (this.isSignInResponse(httpRequest)) {
                logger.debug("authenticating with token");
                principal = this.authenticateWithToken(httpRequest, httpResponse);
                this.writeSessionToken(httpRequest, principal);
                this.redirectToOriginalUrl(httpRequest, httpResponse);
            }

            // is principal in session?
            if (principal == null && this.sessionTokenExists(httpRequest)) {
                logger.debug("authenticating with session token");
                principal = this.authenticateWithSessionToken(httpRequest,
                        httpResponse);
            }

            // if not authenticated at this point, redirect to login page
            System.out.println("httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString() <><> " + httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
            System.out.println("Matcher <><><> " + Pattern.compile(this.excludedUrlsRegex).matcher(httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString()).find());

            boolean excludedUrl = httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains(this.loginPage) || (this.excludedUrlsRegex != null
                            && !this.excludedUrlsRegex.isEmpty() && Pattern
                            .compile(this.excludedUrlsRegex)
                            .matcher(httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString()).find());

            System.out.println("excludedUrl <><><> " + excludedUrl);


            if(excludedUrl){
                System.out.println("excludedUrl <><> " + excludedUrl);

            }

            if (!excludedUrl && principal == null) {
                System.out.println("INSIDE  Condition 1");
                if (!FederatedConfiguration.getInstance().getEnableManualRedirect()) {
                    System.out.println("INSIDE  Condition 2");
                    logger.debug("redirecting to identity provider");
                    this.redirectToIdentityProvider(httpRequest, httpResponse);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("INSIDE  Condition 3");
                    logger.debug("redirecting to login page");
                    this.redirectToLoginPage(httpRequest, httpResponse);
                }

                return;
            }
            logger.debug("principal=" + principal);
            System.out.println("excludedUrlsRegex <><> " + excludedUrlsRegex);
            System.out.println("path.toLowerCase() <><> " + path.toLowerCase());
            boolean pathVal =  path.toLowerCase().contains(excludedUrlsRegex);
            System.out.println("pathVal <><> " + pathVal);

                chain.doFilter(new FederatedHttpServletRequest(httpRequest, principal),response);
            }



    }

    protected void redirectToLoginPage(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        String encodedReturnUrl = URLUTF8Encoder
                .encode(getRequestPathAndQuery(httpRequest));
        String redirect = this.loginPage + "?returnUrl=" + encodedReturnUrl;
        httpResponse.setHeader("Location", redirect);
        httpResponse.setStatus(302);
    }

    protected void redirectToIdentityProvider(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        String wctx = getRequestPathAndQuery(httpRequest);
        String redirect = FederatedLoginManager.getFederatedLoginUrl(wctx);

        httpResponse.setHeader("Location", redirect);
        httpResponse.setStatus(302);
    }

    protected void redirectToOriginalUrl(HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        String wctx = httpRequest.getParameter("wctx");
        if (wctx != null) {
            httpResponse.setHeader("Location", wctx);
            httpResponse.setStatus(302);
        }
    }

    protected Boolean isSignInResponse(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")
                && request.getParameter("wa").equals("wsignin1.0")
                && request.getParameter("wresult") != null) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected Boolean sessionTokenExists(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // this could use signed cookies instead of sessions
        return request.getSession().getAttribute(PRINCIPAL_SESSION_VARIABLE) != null;
    }

    protected FederatedPrincipal authenticateWithSessionToken(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        return (FederatedPrincipal) request.getSession().getAttribute(
                PRINCIPAL_SESSION_VARIABLE);
    }

    protected void writeSessionToken(HttpServletRequest request,
            FederatedPrincipal principal) throws IOException {
        request.getSession()
                .setAttribute(PRINCIPAL_SESSION_VARIABLE, principal);
    }

    protected FederatedPrincipal authenticateWithToken(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        String token = request.getParameter("wresult").toString();

        if (token == null) {
            sendError(request, response, 400,
                    "You were supposed to send a wresult parameter with a token");
        }

        FederatedLoginManager loginManager = FederatedLoginManager.fromRequest(
                request, null);

        try {

            System.out.println("token Value <><><><> " + token);
            FederatedPrincipal principal = loginManager.authenticate(token,response);
            System.out.println("principal <<><><> " + principal);
            System.out.println("principal <<><><> " + principal);
            return principal;
        } catch (FederationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            sendError(request, response, 500,
                    "Oops an error occurred validating the token.");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void sendError(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, int errorNum, String message)
            throws IOException {
        // create the session to avoid IllegalStateException: Cannot create
        // a session after the response has been committed.
        request.getSession();
        logger.warn("response " + errorNum + ": " + message);
        response.sendError(errorNum, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    private static String getRequestPathAndQuery(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String reqUri = req.getRequestURI().toString();
        String queryString = req.getQueryString();
        if (queryString != null) {
            reqUri += "?" + queryString;
        }

        return reqUri;
    }
}
```

I have invested whole day but there is no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be a problem with `excludeUrl`. Set it to true and see if that fixes your problem. If it does then you need to debug that code. Also don't set response codes use `httpResponse.sendRedirect(...)`

Comment: The url-pattern "/" for ClaimServlet means that it replaces the DefaultServlet which normally serves the static resources. Maybe that is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thannks  BalusC, You suggestion is worked for me, But there is one environment, when i am running the project from Netbeans, I am getting the exception "Invalid URL Pattern"  and Build fails.